# Fall damage with velocity phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So after realising the fact that velocity increases heavily over time, making time effectively useless in calculations, I decided to go for a velocity based approach, with fall damage increase with velocity, but i've encountered a problem, with my fallDmgAmt variable just resetting to zero, I dont know whats causing this, but heres my code

```js
//fall damage
    this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 0;
    if (
      this.player.body.onFloor() == false &&
      this.player.body.velocity.y >= 250 &&
      this.falling == false
    ) {
      //console.log("falling");
      this.falling = true;
      this.currentFalling=true;
      return;
    }
    
    if(this.falling == true && this.flying==false && this.player.body.velocity.y >= 1){
      if(this.player.body.velocity.y >= 250){
        this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 1;
      }if(this.player.body.velocity.y >= 350){
        this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 2;
      }if(this.player.body.velocity.y >= 450){
        this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 4;
      }if(this.player.body.velocity.y >= 550){
        this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 5;
      }if(this.player.body.velocity.y >= 650){
        this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 6;
      }if(this.player.body.velocity.y >= 750){
        this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 8;
      }if(this.player.body.velocity.y >= 850){
        this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 10; 
      }
      console.log(this.gameState.fallDmgAmt);
    this}
    
    if (this.player.body.onFloor() == true && this.falling == true && this.flying==false) {
      console.log(this.gameState.fallDmgAmt);
      this.health = this.health - this.gameState.fallDmgAmt;
      if (this.health <= 0) {
        this.health = 0;
        this.scene.launch("death");
        this.health = 10;
        this.changeHealth(this.health);
        this.scene.pause();
        this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 0;
      }
      this.changeHealth(this.health);
      this.falling = false;
      this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 0;
      return;
    this}
```

are there any issues im missing, or something with my if loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the firstline

```js
this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 0;
```

Because as soon as the player touches the floor the `velocity` will be `0`.  Depending on your code it might be enough to move this line into the first if-block:

```js
if (
  this.player.body.onFloor() == false &&
  this.player.body.velocity.y >= 250 &&
  this.falling == false
) {
  // you just need to reset to falldamage to 0 when you start a fall
  this.gameState.fallDmgAmt = 0;
  // ...
}
```

**Update:**

Maybe for good measure you could check for

```js
if(this.falling == true && this.flying==false && this.player.body.onFloor() != true){
```

instead of

```js
if(this.falling == true && this.flying==false && this.player.body.velocity.y >= 1){
```

Since you just want to update the `fallDmgAmt` as long as the `player` is in the air and not on the ground. ***Except** if too many calls of the function `onFloor` causes performance issues.*